# Where can I find diagrams for drupal?

Tags: drupal, diagram

I need some diagrams, especially logic database diagram (Entity Relationship Diagram) of Drupal. I've tried http://drupal.org/node/1161 but all the links are broken.

Comment: You should specify what version of Drupal you are looking for, since the database structure and Drupal core has changed quite a bit over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Drupal with MySQL as database, I suggest using the fine "[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.de/products/workbench/)" and reverse engineer the database. No matter the structure, you will find a nice ER-diagramm no matter the Drupal version.

For more figures: Look through the docs and the community pages. There is, for example, a [nice illustration](http://drupal.org/node/650016) how the forms are working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the diagram for Drupal 7:

[image: http://upsitesweb.com/sites/upsites.co/files/drupal7_model_0.png]

Comment: I can install Drupal 7 with several modules which would uses tables not in this diagram. And also install it without some of the modules which create tables in the diagram (eg. taxonomy).

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the database diagrams. Drupal manage its database schema dynamically. Most module will create their own tables when installed, and some of them will create tables when higher-level object are created through the UI or via code. For instance, the SQL storage (ie. the default one) for the Field API will create tables for entity bundles and their fields.

Since the database schema is dynamic, it cannot be presented in a single diagram. This would make sense. You cam however, generate a diagram from a Drupal database using various reverse engineering  tools.